# ASP.NET Health Monitoring 404 Event

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

Does HealthMonitoring have a built-in event that catches 404 errors? I have tried setting up all events (by using webBaseEvent) and I've searched for two days, but I cannot find or trigger an event for a file not found.

I could create my own, but was hoping there was a built in event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You'd have to create a custom event (from webrequesterrorevent) to have HM track it for you.

How to:
Something like this (from memory) in Application_Error in global.asax -

```
public void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
    if (exception != null && exception.GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
       //custom error
       new Http404Event(this, exception).Raise();
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where to you catch the 404 so that you can raise a new event error of the new custom type?

Comment: @Terry, I updated the answer with an example. Here my custom event is called Http404Event and I raise it in the global.asax if it is a 404 error.